# Javascript doesn't return properly?

Tags: javascript, apply

I am in the process of learning Javascript and came across the `apply` function. I thought I could assign my `apply` value to a variable and then print out the contents of the variable. However, I seem to get undefined and I'm not sure why this is happening...

```
var thisObj = {
    fullName: 'test',
  setName: function(firstName, lastName) {
    this.fullName = firstName + " " + lastName
  }
}

function getInput(firstName, lastName, callBack, createdObj) {
    return callBack.apply(createdObj, [firstName, lastName]);
}

var thisObjectInstantiated = getInput("Michael", "Jackson", thisObj.setName, thisObj);
console.log(thisObjectInstantiated); // Why is this undefined?
```

I noticed also if I change the print to do something like this, my name is properly defined.

```
var thisObjectInstantiated = getInput("Michael", "Jackson", thisObj.setName, thisObj);
console.log(thisObj.fullName); // This is defined properly!
```

How come I can't just store the results of the apply within the `thisObjectInstantiated` variable? Thanks.

Comment: Function `setName` doesn't return anything, so it is `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the getInput function, that is calling the setName function, that doesnt return nothing, so thisObjectInstantiated is receiving... nothing!

You would probably want to change your code like this:

```
var thisObj = {
fullName: 'test',
setName: function(firstName, lastName) {
     this.fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
     return this;
   }
 }
```

Comment: return `this` or `this.fullName`?

Comment: as the variable is called thisObjectInstantiated, it will make sense to return a thisObj instance

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the result of the function call, in your code, no value is returned. That's why you get `undefined`.

The code executed without a return value, so the default return value by JavaScript is `undefined`